# Validation based on other field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

> Concern is used

I got 2 fields period and age

```
period can be (0,1,2)
enum period: %w(evergreen,long_term,short_term)
age can be (0,1)
enum age: %w(long_term, evergreen)
```

if age is long_term then no can can select evergreen from period, presence is not true always

How can i add such kind of validation in rails with custom message
"You can not select evergreen if age is long_term"
i am trying

```
validates :period, if: :selection_rule?

def selection_rule
return if age == long_term && period != evergreen 
end
```

what should be the correct way of doing this kind of validation?

Comment: One huge problem with this setup is that those two enums are going to clash since they both define the `evergreen`  and `longterm` methods. Consider what happens when you do `MyModel.evergreen` or `my_module.evergreen?` - which column is it referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom validation error messages in rails model.

```
validate :age_period

def age_period
  errors.add(:period, "can't be selected for this age group") if age == long_term && period != evergreen 
end
```

Comment: You can define that in concern as well. You'll have to require `include ActiveModel::Validations` in your concern, and put the validation in `included` block

Answer (score 0):

For concern, you could try the following:

```
included do
  validate :age_period
end

private

def age_period
  errors.add(:period, "can't be selected if age is long_term") if age == long_term && period == evergreen
end
```